# How to format a column in datagrid control?

Tags: datagrid, vb6

I got this problem trying to format the values of a specific column but gives me error `Object doesn't support this property of method`. How can I fix this issue?

Here is my code:

```
Set dgData.DataSource = rs
dgData.Columns(1).DataFormat = "#,##0.00"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
Dim d As Integer
For i as Integer = 0 to dgData.Rows.Count -1
     d = CInt(dgData.Rows(i).Cells(1).ToString
     d.ToString("#,##0.00")
     dgData.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = d
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

use NumberFormat instead of DataFormat.

Answer (score 0):

Set dgData.DataSource = rs
dgData.Columns(1).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a question that already has many answers, please be sure to add some additional insight into why the response you're providing is substantive and not simply echoing what's already been vetted by the original poster. 
This is especially important in "code-only" answers such as the one you've provided. Also, in this case, you've echoed the advice already given by @mery

Comment: dgData.Columns(1).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"

Comment: Use the 'NumberFormat' method for assigning this "#,##0.00" type of format.

Comment: Use the 'NumberFormat' method for assigning this "#,##0.00" type of format.
This approach uses the Data Grid inbuilt method for formatting the column of data that was bound via the data source.

Comment: You can (and should) edit your answer, rather than create comments which are edits.